# saving the features of an object in an excel file to be trained with svm using Accord.Net

Tags: excel, svm, surf, object-detection, accord.net

I took a look on Surf and SVMs samples in accord library samples.I wonder how can I save the features I get from "SURF" in the excel file, because the feature ( i.e. interest point ) is a record contains some fields and a array of float (Descriptor) and in the SVMs sample all the columns are just a value, no record contains a list, for example in the XOR classification the input (one feature) is

`(x =0 , y=0 , G=1)`

but here I have a record that contains the next fields :

```
( Laplacian  : int ,    Orientation  : float    , Response  : float     ,Scale : float ,    X  :  float , Y   : float  , Descriptor   : [] float   )
```

and I'm not sure but if I want to make like the XOR problem I should add a field of the object name . I found that the SVM takes a matrix, I can't figure out how can I make this compatibility between these two samples, I hope my question is clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear, but I will propose a solution. As a disclaimer, and to avoid further complications, I should say I am the author of this library.

If all you want is to train a SVM using SURF features, then you could skip the Excel part. It should be more useful to create a bag-of-visual-words representation of your images, and then store this representation instead of the SURF features.
It seems this question was asked *before* the image classification sample application was released, so please take a look on it if you are still interested in the answer.

In any case, the bag-of-visual-words model is able to transform your variable-length number of features into fixed length vectors, which should be easier manage, either if you would like to train SVMs or just store then in a file. Here is an example on how to use the BoW model to extract fixed-length features:

```
// Create bag-of-words (BoW) with the given number of words
BagOfVisualWords bow = new BagOfVisualWords(numberOfWords);

bow.Compute( ... ); // pass all images in the training set

// And then you can create a fixed-length 
// representation of an given image using
double[] featureVector = bow.GetFeatureVector(image);
```

I will refrain from posting any links here so it doesn't looks like I am promoting my own project even further, but the classification sample application is available both under your start menu, if you have installed using the executable installer; and in the project's website.